# I Need Help in pivoting a data using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and would appreciate any help.

My Question is , I have been trying to Pivot a particular data using vba, I am nowhere with it.

My original data looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkQ8J.png)

### Input Table

```
New Name    month   value       
a   Ram     PER_AUG14   100     
b   Sham    PER_AUG14   150     
b   John    PER_SEP14   160     
d   Ram     PER_OCT14   180     
b   John    PER_JUL14   190     
d   Ram     PER_AUG14   300     
c   John    PER_SEP14   400     
a   Sham    PER_AUG14   500
```

### Desired result

```
Name    Month           a     b     c     d
Ram         PER_AUG14    100               300
John        PER_SEP14          160   400    
Sham        PER_AUG14   500    150      
John        PER_JUL14          190      
Ram         PER_OCT14                      180
```

Please help me as i am stuck on this... 
Thank You

Comment: You can do this easily with a Pivot Table and some formatting.  And, if VBA is an absolute necessity, record a macro while you are doing that, and then edit the code to clean it up.

Answer (score -1):

Why use VBA? Why not just use a [Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPpxV.png) table in Excel?

`Mark the input data -> Insert -> PivotTable`

Comment: as mr.bjerre says, Excel has this function built in. Unless there is a valid reason that vba must be used, this is the easiest option. Just set your data source to your original table, put the "name" and "month" fields in the rows, the "new" field in the columns, and then the "value" field in the value section.